# Google API test in postman

Tags: google-maps-api-3, postman

I am beginning to use API's so I'm using Google Maps API.
Through postman I'm trying to get find a place from text so I went through the documentation and saw it is obligatory to use two parameters: input and input type.

I am writing this line with the two mentioned parameters, that according to the documentation should be enough to get a result.

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Amphitheatre&inputtype=<string>&key=MYKEY`

However I am getting this error, could someone advice me what I am doing wrong? I also tried writing in the parameter `input type`the option `textquery`like it's shown in the documentation, but still the same error.

```json
{
    "candidates": [],
    "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"
}
```

I am writing something wrong or missing some detail?

***UPDATE***

Thank you everyone for your input, as some people commented here my error was to use the `inputtype=<string>`I changed to `inputtype=textquery` without the `<>` symbols and it is working!

Comment: Do the [examples in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#maps_http_places_findplacefromtext_mca-txt) work for you?  The values there look different from those in your example.

Comment: I get a result (a placeId) from: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Amphitheatre&inputtype=textquery&key=MYKEY`

Comment: Try removing the <> around "string"